# Patents and distribution rights

Tags: distribution, rights

We have been given sole distribution rights in Africa of a patented product from Poland. We've also just discovered that one of our clients who requested a sample "for their showroom" has had the design copied in China and is flogging a really bad remake here in South Africa. Does our distribution rights automatically transfer the patent? Is there any protection that we can rely on?

Comment: Are there patents in South Africa or China? A polish patent is enforceable only in Poland, so without a national patent, there's not a chance to do anything against anything  anywhere outside Poland.

Answer (score 1):

If the patent includes regions in Africa, you should be able to enforce exclusivity, but, as DonQuiKong mentions, patents are specific to regions, and it may not cover South Africa.

- You need to check which international regions the patent was filed and granted in.